# jquery gmap3 error

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

I'm using jquery and gmap3. I've this error code

```
08-01 12:33:30.000: E/Web Console(13908): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'address' in [{"lat":"40.7909276","lng":"14.3690722","data":{"drive":"false","zip":"80059","city":"Torre del Greco"}}]
```

I'm trying to insert my points in a cluster. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Its too late but the solution is available in the below link http://gmap3.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=2323

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error. As I found out the reason is incorrect data representation in JS var array variable.
That error happens when you have for example 'unnecessary quotes' around array elements like:

`var geoResult = ['{\"lat\":49.99649843859962,\"lng\":36.226598247885704, \"data\":{\"id\":\"5125f498caeccbeb7c5e2546\",\"street\":\"Dzerzhyns\\u0027kyi District\",\"name\":\"Arsenal\"}}', '{\"lat\":49.98246816844554,\"lng\":36.263782382011414, \"data\":{\"id\":\"5123dfa9eb8cc0a3bcf6a2df\",\"street\":\"Kominternivs\\u0027kyi District\",\"name\":\"Club\"}}'];`

As you can see there is quotes:
`var geoResult = ['{}'];`
they are causing error.